# private vcpkg registry - private port depends on another private port

Tags: vcpkg

I had a private vcpkg registry, which defines 2 ports: A and B.

If port A depends on port B, I defined ports/A/vcpkg.json:

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": [
        {
          "name": "B",
          "version>=": "0.0.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since B is also in a private registry, so i created a vcpkg-configuration.json under ports/A:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg-configuration.schema.json",
  "registries": [
    {
      "kind": "git",
      "repository": "git@bitbucket.org:username/privatevcpkgregistry",
      "baseline": "2613f50507cb647f540f434ed239664bf08317fa",
      "packages": [ "B" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However the private registry is apparently ignored here, so when a client application depends on A, it cannot find the B from the same registry.
I also tried to use "overlay-ports" but it doesn't work as well.